# Image compression in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, image-compression, mozjpeg

I am trying to compress images with [mozjpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mozjpeg-js) when I implemented it in node.js according to the docs it worked fine.

```
const input = fs.readFileSync("in.ppm");
const out = mozjpeg.encode(input, { quality: 85 });
```

I need to do the compression on the client-side, so I tried to do the same with react-native since react-native doesn't contain core node modules such as fs, I need to go for a third party library [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) for file reading.

When I tried to execute `mozjpeg.encode(input, { quality: 85 });` in react-native it throws `Unrecognized input file format --- perhaps you need -targa`

server-side implementation

```
const mozjpeg = require("mozjpeg-js");
const fs = require("fs");

const input = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
const out = mozjpeg.encode(input, { quality: 85 });
console.error(out.stderr);
fs.writeFileSync("out.jpg", out.data);
```

client-side implementation

```
fs.readFile(image.path).then(data => {
    const out = mozjpeg.encode(data, { quality: 85 });
    console.log(out);
}
```

Here is the list of thing I tried

- Tried giving input in hex, buffer, base64 and plain URL string.
- Since the Android URL contains `file://` as prefix I tried to remove them also.

Comment: I used https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-resizer with quality to compress image

Comment: Yes, i am currently using that but i wanted to migrate to mozjpeg to reduce file size.

Comment: The issue is almost certainly something with the encoding (assuming the file is being read correctly). Because `mozjpeg` expects the file to be binary encoded maybe something like `Buffer.from(data, 'utf8')` as `readFile` from `react-native-fs` is `utf8` by default.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I don't know about `mozjpeg` but I prefer to use pure JavaScript way on the environment of problem to solve my problem.

I guess your thought fell in one-way bios, leave away the NodeJS solution, you are in the react-native environment so use [React Native Compress Image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-compress-image) or [React Native Image Resizer](https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-resizer).

Based on my experiences I prefer to use the second one, the [React Native Image Resizer](https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-resizer).

After install, use it like below:

```
ImageResizer.createResizedImage(
  imageUri,
  newWidth,
  newHeight,
  compressFormat,
  quality
)
  .then( resizedImageUri => {

    // the resizedImageUri is accessible here to use.

  }).catch( err => {

  // Catch any error here.

});
```

Comment: I am already using React Native Image Resizer, I just want to migrate from that to mozjpeg.

Comment: Dear @Badri, why you wanna migrate from awesome and update library to a library for another environment that is not compatible and has many issues?

Comment: well i compared both the compressions, for me mozjpeg seems to have better compression technique and give the output file more 20% lower compared to react-native-compression which is important to what i am developing.

Comment: @Badri, We have three environments, RN, Node, Browser, in the Browser, compressor methods use canvas and base64 to calculate on an image and make some changes like resizing, rotate or compress. in the Node environment the _mozjpeg_ uses [`cjpeg`](https://github.com/as-com/mozjpeg-js/blob/master/lib/cjpeg.js) that is based on [MozJPEG](https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg) and `fs` that doesn't exist in the RN, in the RN it is needed to use Device Native modules, iOS: objective-c and Android: JAVA, I know you said the mozjpeg is better in compressing but it not related to RN environment.

Comment: @Badri, Also there is another good RN library that we used inside our project. its purpose is cropping image but one of its abilities is compressing grabbed pictures. I will add a separate answer.

Comment: Yes i completely agree with you, RN doesn't have fs, there is a package for that react-native-fs which is used to read files the output will be in base64/ascii or utf-8. since MozJpeg only supports binary buffer i tried to convert which obviously didn't work,My question is whether i am missing something in the process of converting to binary buffer. BTW, i am already using what you suggested both libraries react-native-crop-picker to select the image and react-native-image-resizer to resize to various sizes,I did research as best as i could need to reduce that 10-15% size and get best Quality.

Comment: Dear @Badri, I hope you find the best way and solution. By the way, I leave an upvote to your question. thanks for the good negotiation.❤️

Answer (score 2):

Also, there is another good [React-Native image crop picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker) library that purpose is grabbing some images and cropping them but it has a good ability to compress it. maybe this library has a good compress algorithm like *mozjpeg*.

It can open camera, open gallery or use a constant image, even you can turn of cropping:

```
ImagePicker.openCamera({
  width: 300,
  height: 400,
  compressImageQuality: 0.2
}).then(image => {
  // do what you want
}).catch(e => {
  // handle error
});
```

Good to config and it has many options for tuning. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Dear @Badri, if it is possible please release a simple tiny, re-production of your project into GitHub or GitLab then I clone it. maybe I could help you.

Comment: Thanks i post the link ASAP

Comment: react-native-image-crop-picker is a great package, but the compression quality is decent. You can find other packages, such as imagemin, that compress better quality and file size. But sadly it's not for react native.

Comment: @AnhNguyen, Sorry, I didn't get what you mean! what's your purpose for this comment? and how I can help you?

Comment: @AmerllicA No I'm not asking for your help. I just comment your answer. Can't I?

Comment: Dear @AnhNguyen, definitely, you can, I only haven't understood. ok. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can find in [mozjpeg-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mozjpeg-js) doc that the input argument is:

> a typed array or buffer of data

---

`fs.readFile` return type in client-side (`react-native-fs`) is `Promise<string>` and return contents. ([Doc](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#readfilefilepath-string-encoding-string-promisestring))

But in server-side (`fs`), `fs.readFileSync` return buffer object. ([Doc](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options))

---

So you can change string to a typed array with this function:

```
function str2ta(str) {
  var bufView = new Uint16Array(str.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char
  for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i<strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return bufView;
}
```

Comment: I have seen that on docs that's why i mentioned that i have given input in hex, buffer, base64 and plain URL string. BTW i used this function to convert function base64ToHex(str) {
          console.log(str)
          const raw = atob(str);
          let result = '';
          for (let i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
            const hex = raw.charCodeAt(i).toString(16).toLowerCase();
            result += ((hex.length === 2 ? hex : '0' + hex) + ' ');
          }
          return result.toLowerCase();
        }

Comment: Why you did not test `typed array`? Your `base64ToHex` function return string, but my `str2ta` return typed array @Badri

Comment: I tried typed arrays, unit8buffer, int8buffer after trying all that only i posted my question here sorry for not mentioning more clear on inputs i have tried, and i tried your function also still the same error throws. I tried hex bcoz fs from node returns hex buffer by default as it worked in my server code i tried that as a last resort @Mohsen

Answer (score 0):

Expo has a component that does exactly this: [Image Manipulator](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagemanipulator)